# WebLogic Scripting Tool - Ant Task Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find the OffLine WLST class

Tags: java, ant, scripting, weblogic, wlst

The goal here is to connect to our dev instance and restart a managed server in the WebLogic console. I've attempted to reboot the managed server using the wlserver task but ran into a number of issues when attempting to start the server. I'm now attempting to use the wlst tool which I'm able to successfully reboot via command line. For some reason, the following ant task is unable to find the weblogic.jar file located in my weblogic server directory. I could use a fresh set of eyes to see where the issue is coming from. I'm currently receiving the following error:

"Could not find the  OffLine WLST class"

Here is a snippet of my ant task:

```
<property name="weblogic.home" value="C:\wls12210"/>
<target name="Restart OACore">
<path id="weblogic.lib.path">
        <fileset dir="${weblogic.home}\wlserver\server\lib\">
            <include name="web*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <taskdef name="wlst" classname="weblogic.ant.taskdefs.management.WLSTTask" classpathref="weblogic.lib.path"/>
    <wlst debug="true" executeScriptBeforeFile="false" failOnError="true">
        <script>
            connect('username','password','t3://usnowebldev01:7001')
            shutdown('StandardRods')
            start('StandardRods')
        </script>
    </wlst>
</target>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error was a dependency conflict in the ant scripts property settings. Issue  resolved.